# Cubic spline interpolation of function

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate the following function using the MATLAB function `spline`,

[image]

at equidistant points `xi = i./n`, `i = 0,1,...,n`, and for `n = 2^j`, `j = 4,5,...,14`.

For each calculation, I record the maximum error at the points `x = 0:0.001:1` and plot these errors against `n` using a `loglog` plot.

Below is the code,

```
index=1

for j = 4:1:14;
    n = 2^j;
    i = 0:1:n;
    xi = i./n;
    yi = ((exp(3*xi))*sin(200.*(xi.^2))) ./(1+20.*(xi.^2));
    x = 0:.001:1;
    ye = ((exp(3*x))*sin(200*x.^2)) ./(1+20*x.^2);
    yp = spline(x,xi,yi);
    err = ye - yp;
    merr(index) = max(err);
    index = index+1;
end

n1 = 10:10:170;
loglog(n1, merr,'.')
xlabel('n');
ylabel('errors');
title('Cubic Splines');
```

but when I run the code, I got the following error:

> Error using  *  Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in  (line 9) yi = ((exp(3*xi))*sin(200.*(xi.^2)))
>   ./(1+20.*(xi.^2));

I'm just starting learning MatLab, can anyone help?

Comment: Beware that errors are usually computed with a [mean squared error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) or at least with an `abs` function. In your code, `err = ye - yp` and `err = abs(ye - yp)` give different results.

Comment: Your 'loglog' command will throw an error because `numel(n1)~=numel(merr)` but other than that, I think my answer explains the error message you get and a `spline` error you will get.

Answer (score 1):

You want [element-wise multiplication](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html) (`.*`) for the following part of code:

```
yi = ((exp(3*xi))*sin(200.*(xi.^2))) ./(1+20.*(xi.^2));
```

should be

```
yi = ((exp(3*xi)).*sin(200.*(xi.^2))) ./(1+20.*(xi.^2));
```

The same issue is present for the computation of `ye`.

When you use `mtimes` (`*`), MATLAB tries to do matrix multiplication, which in your case (1-by-n times 1-by-n) is invalid.

Then you will run into a problem with your `spline` command.  Change it to `yp = spline(xi,yi,x);` so that the values at which you want to interploate (`x`) are the last argument.